# I want import android.provider.Calendar;

Tags: android, calendar

i want import

```
import android.provider.Calendar;
```

how can i import this class in my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is still not part of the public SDK.

You can still read the data though, I wrote an article about it: http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=151

Comment: Hi kannappan, personally I use intents for this because it doesn't require permissions, is less error-prone and allows the user to both preview and fine-control changes. Downside is every single new/modified event needs user interaction, so it wouldn't be suitable for say a custom calendar sync app. I think people do push calendar data via the provider or other methods but I've not done that myself.

Answer (score 2):

The class isn't public.

See http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ae95c372af20f39e?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

you can use the GIT file,it's free from google.in the git you will find all the classes of calender for android.

Comment: You can find the Git file here 
http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git;a=summary 
or just give me your mail ID i will mail you the Git.